# How to get href from an element from sibling class search?

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I would like to get the `href` from the following html

```
<a class="AirQuality--detailsButton--DBdLS Button--primary--1UQTP" href="/en-IN/forecast/air-quality/l/bf01d09009561812f3f95abece23d16e123d8c08fd0b8ec7ffc9215c0154913c" target="_self">See Details</a>
```

where `href` to be extracted based on class `class="AirQuality--detailsButton--DBdLS Button--primary--1UQTP"` from element `a`.

I tried doing the following but not returning anything.

```
response.css('a.AirQuality--detailsButton--DBdLS Button--primary--1UQTP::attr(href)').get()
```

Full html could be fetched through scrapy by

```
scrapy shell "https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/bf01d09009561812f3f95abece23d16e123d8c08fd0b8ec7ffc9215c0154913c"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried using xpath? `//a[contains(text(), 'See Details')/@href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two class name . so you need to add dot(.) .Now it's working.

```
response.css('a.AirQuality--detailsButton--DBdLS.Button--primary--1UQTP::attr(href)').get()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. May I know how did you know there are two buttons? In html they were separated by just a space.

Comment: Because there are a space between them and that space is separated each class name and we need to use dot instead of space. Thanks